# Setting up a default ORACLE_SID in linux

Tags: linux, oracle

Every time I log in to oracle, I am given an error:

> `ORA-12162 TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified`

So I am forced to run this:

```
ORACLE_SID=mydb; export ORACLE_SID
```

I'd like to set `mydb` to be the default `ORACLE_SID`. I have searched for ways to do this, but I'm too rusty on linux to pull this off. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
[oracle]$ --> in .profile add export ORACLE_SID=mydb
-bash: in: Permission denied

[root]$ chsh -s /bin/bash oracle
Changing shell for oracle.
Shell changed.
```

Here's what my tnsnames.ora looks like:

```
MYDB=
     (DESCRIPTION=
             (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))
             (CONNECT_DATA=
                     (SERVICE_NAME=mydb,
                     SID=mydb)
             )
     )
```

Comment: Try adding export ORACLE_SID=mydb to your .profile file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to define the ORACLE_SID and export it in the oracle user's `.bash_profile`. This means these two steps are run each time the oracle user logs in, so it's possibly more of a hack, but it works:

Here's the short version. If you're not sure what you're doing, go to the detailed section where I explain what's going on.

```
$ sudo -i
$ chsh /bin/bash oracle
$ sudo su - oracle
$ cd
$ vi .bash_profile
$ i

...
# User specific environment and startup programs
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH

###### ADD YOUR SID STUFF HERE ######
ORACLE_SID=mydb
export ORACLE_SID
~
~
```

<kbd>esc</kbd>, `:w!` to save, `:q` to quit.

```
$ exit
$ sudo su - oracle
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
```

That's it.

---

## Details

**Defining the shell (Optional)**

If you're like me, and the sys admins set up the oracle account to automatically disable the shell on logout, you'll need to first redefine the shell for the oracle user (as root):

```
$ sudo -i
$ chsh /bin/bash oracle
```

**Edit the profile**
Then you need to login as the oracle user and edit `.bash_profile`:

```
$ sudo su - oracle
$ cd
$ vi .bash_profile
$ i
```

You're now editing the `.bash_profile` in the VI editor. It should look something like this:

```
# .bash_profile
...
# User specific environment and startup programs
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
~
~
```

What you need to do is add your SID stuff after `export PATH`, so it should look like this:

```
# User specific environment and startup programs
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH

###### ADD YOUR SID STUFF HERE ######
ORACLE_SID=mydb
export ORACLE_SID
~
~
```

OK, now you gotta save the file, and exit vi:

<kbd>esc</kbd>, `:w!` to save, `:q` to quit.

> Troubleshooting Sidebar: If you have an issue saving the file because the oracle user doesn't have privileges, then you'll have to do it using the root user, which means you'll have to find oracle's `.bash_profile` file, which is probably in `/home/oracle/` *(Remember, it's a hidden file, so use `ls -a` to see it instead of `ls`)*

OK, so assuming you're still logged in as the oracle user, you need to logout and log back in. That will activate the code you just added, and define the ORACLE_SID.

```
$ exit
$ sudo su - oracle
```

Comment: `export ORACLE_SID=mydb` is one step. Also I'm pretty sure `PATH` is already marked for export so you could save another step there.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I appreciate the feedback. My goal with this answer was more about baby steps rather than efficiency though. I found the process confusing, so I wanted to be sure to spell it out for others who were confused as well as my future self who probably wouldn't have to do this for years, then do it again out of nowhere. But again, much obliged.

Comment: ORACLE_SID=mydb  - What is mydb? Where did you get it from?

Answer (score 0):

There is a script provided by Oracle called oraenv, that usually live in your local bin directory. In you bash_profile, you would do something like:

```
set ORAENV_ASK=N
. oraenv mydb
```

Note that it is "dot space oraenv"